# How to implement repeat untill (condition) loop in promela?

Tags: promela, spin

Which would be right approach to do :

```
repeat{
...
} until(<condition>)
```

in Promela ?

I have tried :

```
do::
 //..
(condition) -> break;
od
```

and

```
do ::
  //..
  if::(condition) -> break;
  else
  fi;
od
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt is incorrect, because if `<condition>` is not `true` the process will simply block forever.

Your second attempt is functionally correct. Personally, I would prefer a minor variant to your solution which does not drop the `true` entry condition for executing the *bulk code*.

---

Given

```cpp
repeat{
    // bulk code
} until(<condition>)
```

you have the following options:

- [do](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/do.html):

  ```cpp
  do
      :: true ->
          // bulk code
          if
              :: <condition> ->
                  break;
              :: else;
          fi;
  od;
  ```

  or

  ```cpp
  do
      :: true ->
          // bulk code
          if
              :: ! <condition>;
              :: else ->
                  break;
          fi;
  od;
  ```
- [goto](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/goto.html):

  ```cpp
  L1:
      // bulk code
      if
          :: <condition>;
          :: else
              -> goto L1;
      fi;
  ```

  or

  ```cpp
  L1:
      // bulk code
      if
          :: ! <condition>
              -> goto L1;
          :: else;
      fi;
  ```
- [unless](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/unless.html) **(do not use!)**:

  ```cpp
  do
      :: true ->
          d_step {
              // bulk code
          }
  od unless { <condition> };
  ```

  Note that there are two catches with this approach:

  - it assumes that the value of `<condition>` is altered within `// bulk code` and not anywhere else in the code (*e.g. by some other process*)
  - depending on the content of `// bulk code`, it might not possible to use [`d_step`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/d_step.html) at all.

  Only in the case in which the instruction altering the evaluation of `<condition>` is *precisely* the **last one** inside `// bulk code` then one is allowed to drop [`d_step`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/d_step.html) without affecting the semantics.

  To see why this is the case, observe the behaviour of `Spin` on the following code example:

  ```cpp
  active proctype example()
  {
      int cc = 0;
      do
          :: true ->
              printf("before %d\n", cc);
              cc++;
              printf("after  %d\n", cc);
      od unless { cc == 3 };
  }
  ```

  which has the following output:

  ```cpp
  ~$ spin test.pml 
        before 0
        after  1
        before 1
        after  2
        before 2
  1 process created
  ```

  since `cc++` alters the evaluation of `cc == 3` but is not the last instruction of the code sequence, the statement `after 3` is never printed on screen.

---

**EDIT:**

Of course one could also try another variant of code with the `unless` statement, **e.g.**

```cpp
bool flag;
do
    :: true ->
        // bulk code
        flag = true;
        flag = false;
od unless { flag && <condition> };
```

This is obviously always correct, even in the general case, but it clogs the source code with additional variables that are not part of the original problem, *so I would still discourage the use of `unless` to replace `do/until`*.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```cpp
active proctype example()
{
    int cc = 0;
    bool flag = false;
    do
        :: true ->
            printf("before %d\n", cc);
            cc++;
            printf("after  %d\n", cc);
            flag = true;
            flag = false;
    od unless { flag && (cc == 3) };
}
```

and indeed it yields the correct output:

```cpp
~$ spin test.pml 
      before 0
      after  1
      before 1
      after  2
      before 2
      after  3
1 process created
```